# How to find 2 local maximum values of y for a given range

Tags: r, math

```r
#!My question requires me to find 2 local maximum for y using this equation: 
x <-seq(-5,5,length =10001)
y<-(10 *((x-1)^2 )^(1/3))/(x^2+9) 
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

I believe I can get one max value by either max(y) or y[which.max(y)]. 
But I can't find the other max value since the graph have 2 peaks.

```r
y[which.max(y)]
#> [1] 1.637347
max(y)
#> [1] 1.637347
```

I tried finding the second local maximum using this way but not sure if it's correct

```r
y[which.max(x>2)]
#> [1] 0.7695067
```

Created on 2019-03-24 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Is that cube root just for the numerator or the entire expression?

Comment: Just for the numerator

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather roundabout way of getting it done (correctly?).

```
#Library kader for cuberoot() function
library('kader')

#Declaring x and calculating y
varX <- seq(-5, 5, length = 10001)
crootX <- kader:::cuberoot((varX-1)^2)
actY <- (10*crootX)/(varX^2+9)

#Storage variable for the maxima
outs <- c()

#Looping through y values looking for those values that are greater than both the preceding AND succeeding values
for(i in 1:length(actY)){
  if(actY[i] > actY[i-1] && actY[i] > actY[i+1]){
    outs[i] <- actY[i]
  }
}

#Subsetting said values and output
outs <- subset(outs, !is.na(outs))
outs
#[1] 1.6373473 0.8818895
```

Comment: So if I just use ^(1/3) instead of the cuberoot() function is it less efficient?